# MacOS - Can't install brew

Tags: homebrew

When I try to install brew using their terminal command:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Brew starts downloading but then stops saying: Can't install  software because it is not currently in the Software Update Server. What should I do?

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbNVS.png) is what the terminal says about the error

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too.

1. Solved it by downloading Command-Line-Tools from Apple Developer Portal. Accessible even with a free apple developer account.

https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.14_for_Xcode_10.1/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.14_for_Xcode_10.1.dmg

2. You might also have to agree to terms and conditions. Terminal will prompt you if necessary, and all you have todo is type `agree`